# Mysql Query with AND condition is not working as Expected

Tags: c#, mysql

Am new to MYsql and was worked in MS sql, I created a stored procedure with 2 parameters, one is String and another Int, but when i execute query it gives me same out put for all values, I am expecting 0 records when Two conditions are not matched, but it is showing same records for whatever input I give, Please let me know what i have missed

I have attached screen shots and let me know any more info needed

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `&& BatchID == batchID` will be true for all rows, as the latter refers to the column, not the parameter. See duplicate for workarounds.

Comment: Use `AND BatchID == batchID`

Comment: @Tushar no, [`&&` and `AND` are equivalent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and).

Comment: That did a trick changing  BatchID = batch ,but its just single "=" not  "=="Yes, CodeCaster, both && and AND are same,